# Filtering on multiple conditions using javascript filter

Tags: javascript

Before anyone calls duplicate please read it through first...

I was trying to use the filter function with multiple conditions but doesn't seem to work and alot of solutions to this roughly come out to say I can do...

```
const data = [
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: 2, SectionID: 9},
    {CatalogID: 2, SectionID: 9},
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6},
    {CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6},
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6}
]

data.filter(f=>f.SectionID == 6 && f.SectionID == 0 && f.CatalogID == -1)

let a = data.filter(function(e) {
        return e.SectionID == 6 && e.SectionID == 0 && e.CatalogID == -1
    });
console.log(a);
```

But those return empty... But when I loop through the data object, like this...

```
let holder = [];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i].SectionID === 6 || data[i].SectionID === 0 || data[i].CatalogID === -1) holder.push(data[i]);
}
console.log(holder);
holder = [];
```

Then it does the job, but its not pretty.

Is there something glaringly obvious that is wrong with the code I provided, that is not popping out at me?

** EDIT **
The result I am looking for is this...

```
{CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
{CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
{CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
{CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6},
{CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6},
{CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
{CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6}
```

Comment: How can `sectionID` be both `0` and `6` at the same time?

Comment: I think you want `(f.SectionID == 6 || f.SectionID == 0) && f.CatalogID == -1`

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: The loop version uses `||` condition, the `filter` version uses `&&` condition.

Comment: Notice the difference between the filter and for loop. In filter you are using `&&` while in the for loop you are using `||` for a comparison.

Comment: @Barmar, tried that, all it returns is 4 records.. its very possible that SectionID can be 6 and also a 0 because this data is based on grid rows, so the SectionID that is a 0, and also the CatalogID being -1 are actually empty rows... I also made an edit with desired result

Comment: SectionID can't be both 6 and 0 in the same object.

Comment: From the sample results, I think you want: `f.SectionID == 6 || (f.SectionID == 0 && f.CatalogID == -1)`

Comment: @Barmar, I am looking at the data object being returned to me for my grid's datasource and I assure you that it is indeed 6 and 0, as I shown in the data object.

Comment: Which object in the array has two different values of sectionID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.sectionID = 6 && f.sectionID == 0` can't ever be true -- there can only be one `sectionID` value in a specific object `f`.

You need to use `||` to match different values of the same `sectionID` property. Then use `&&` to combine condition with `catalogID`.

```js
const data = [
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: 2, SectionID: 9},
    {CatalogID: 2, SectionID: 9},
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6},
    {CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6},
    {CatalogID: -1, SectionID: 0},
    {CatalogID: 3, SectionID: 6}
]

let a = data.filter(f => f.SectionID == 6 || ( f.SectionID == 0 && f.CatalogID == -1))

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Yep, that worked perfectly. Ah, ok now I know what you meant about the SectionID...my apologies